# Devise usermailer errors when trying to customize: undefined local variable or method `controller' for #<UserMailer:0x007fac55fe3ba8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm trying to customize my devise user emails.

I did the following:

**routes.rb**

```
 devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations", :sessions => "sessions", :confirmations => "confirmations", :passwords => "passwords", :omniauth_callbacks => "authentications" }
```

end

**devise.rb**

```
  config.mailer = "UserMailer"
```

**class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base**

```
include Devise::Mailers::Helpers # Needed for Devise
default from: "default@mydomain.com"

  def confirmation_instructions(record)
    @resource = record
    mail( :from => "default@mydomain.com",
          :to => record.email,
          :subject => "XXXXXXXXX"
        )
  end
```

**confirmation_instructions.html.erb**

```
 <p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', user_confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @resource.confirmation_token) %></p>
```

This results in the error:

```
NameError in Registrations#create

Showing /Users/xxx/Sites/x/app/views/user_mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb where line #5 raised:

undefined local variable or method `controller' for #<UserMailer:0x007fac55fe3ba8>
```

Any idea what's wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

If you are using :reconfirmable module, then it requires unconfirmed_email column. So you have to add that column in your db(by creating a new migration for adding column)

However if you are not planning to use module :recoverable. disable it using following command(in intializers/devise.rb):-

config.reconfirmable = false

as it is enabled by default.